# Unicode problems when using io.StringIO to mock a file

Tags: python, unicode, stringio

I am using an `io.StringIO` object to mock a file in a unit-test for a class. The problem is that this class seems expect all strings to be unicode by default, but the builtin `str` does not return unicode strings:

```
>>> buffer = io.StringIO()
>>> buffer.write(str((1, 2)))
TypeError: can't write str to text stream
```

But

```
>>> buffer.write(str((1, 2)) + u"")
6
```

works. I assume this is because the concatenation with a unicode string makes the result unicode as well. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The io package provides python3.x compatibility. In python 3, strings are unicode by default.

Your code works fine with the standard StringIO package,

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> StringIO().write(str((1,2)))
>>>
```

If you want to do it the python 3 way, use unicode() in stead of str(). You have to be explicit here.

```
>>> io.StringIO().write(unicode((1,2)))
6
```